# Expression Trees and datarow

Tags: .net, linq, datatable, expression-trees

####UPDATE

The query should return values from a lookup table according to various criteria. The program should build these expressions at runtime using meta information.
Any where expressions should be possible.

Possible expressions can be:

```
DataRow test = lookup.Where(item => (item.Field<string>("K1_Filter") =="1100")).FirstOrDefault();

DataRow test = lookup.Where(item => (item.Field<string>("K1_Filter") =="1100" && item.Field<string>("K2_Filter") =="abc" )).FirstOrDefault();

DataRow test = lookup.Where(item => (item.Field<string>("K1_Filter").Contains("1100") && item.Field<string>("K2_Filter") =="abc" )).FirstOrDefault();
```

#

I need to build an expression tree for this query:

```
using  ExpressionLinq = System.Linq.Expressions;
IQueryable<DataRow> lookup = dataTable.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();
DataRow test = lookup.Where(item => (item.Field<string>("K1_Filter") == "1100")).FirstOrDefault();
```

that's what I've come to:

```
ExpressionLinq.ParameterExpression pe = ExpressionLinq.Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRow), "item");  

ExpressionLinq.Expression right = ExpressionLinq.Expression.Constant("1100"); 
MethodInfo mi = typeof(DataRowExtensions).GetMethod("Field", new Type[] { typeof(DataRow), typeof(string) });

mi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

List<ExpressionLinq.Expression> list = new List<ExpressionLinq.Expression>();
ExpressionLinq.ParameterExpression datarow = ExpressionLinq.Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRow), "item");

ExpressionLinq.ConstantExpression constant = ExpressionLinq.Expression.Constant("K1_Filter", typeof(string));

list.Add(datarow);
list.Add(constant);

ReadOnlyCollection<ExpressionLinq.Expression> collection = new ReadOnlyCollection<ExpressionLinq.Expression>(list);

ExpressionLinq.MethodCallExpression methodCall = 
    ExpressionLinq.Expression.Call(null, mi, collection);
ExpressionLinq.Expression predicateBody = ExpressionLinq.Expression.Equal(methodCall, right);


ExpressionLinq.MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = 
    ExpressionLinq.Expression.Call(
        typeof(System.Linq.Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { lookup.ElementType },
        lookup.Expression,
        ExpressionLinq.Expression.Lambda<Func<DataRow, bool>>(predicateBody, new ExpressionLinq.ParameterExpression[] { pe }));


    ExpressionLinq.MethodCallExpression firstordefault = 
        ExpressionLinq.Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        "FirstOrDefault",
        new Type[] { lookup.ElementType },
        whereCallExpression);

var results = lookup.Provider.CreateQuery<DataRow>(firstordefault);
```

---

The last line returns the following error message:

> System.ArgumentException: "Argument expression is not valid"

Can anybody help me? I can't find the bug.

Comment: What you exactly want to do? Querying on fields generically?

Comment: I want to make a dynamic linq query on a datatable. The aim is to be able to extend or change the where condition.

Comment: I see, can you give example of use cases?

Comment: I added an update in my question with examples.